# ViewChild is not defined

Tags: angular

```
@ViewChild(AlertComponent) alert: AlertComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    debugger;
    var msg: Message ={ message: 'Saved successfully!', status: true };
    console.log(this.alert.show(msg))
  }

  success(){
    debugger;
    //Saved successfully show the message
    var msg: Message ={ message: 'Saved successfully!', status: true };
    this.alert.show(msg);
  }
```

this is my code. I am unable to call the alert service. It is showing undefined for the viewchild

**Alert Component:**

```
export class AlertComponent {
    message: Message = null;
    constructor() {}
    show(msg: Message) {
        debugger;
        this.message = msg;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.message = null;
        }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is AlertComponent implemented in the .html file?

Comment: export class AlertComponent {
  message: Message = null;
  constructor(){ }



  show(msg: Message ){
    debugger;
    this.message = msg;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.message = null;
    }, 2000)
  }
}

Comment: No, if you use a ViewChild you have to use the AlertComponent in the template of the current component. Like: <alert-component></alert-component>. This part of the template I want to see.

Comment: Okay,Thank you.
I have a value cartcount in app component i want update the value from other component.How can i do that?

Comment: Please show how you used your `AlertComponent` in the template where you want to use the `@ViewChild`

Comment: @maruthi burkani According to your question here in the comments, I would recommend to create a new question for that.

Comment: Please add to the question the relevant part of the template markup (including possible loops and conditions around the child component tag).

Answer (score -2):

You should use `Alert Component` in the template of the parent component. Anyway  you should try another type of communication between components like input/output or a service.
More info: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: why should he change his approach?

Comment: is not mandatory, but i would give you 2 reason:
- is the angular preferred way
- clean and more readable code